# Subclass PFUser in swift

Tags: properties, swift, parse-platform, subclass, pfuser

I wanna subclass the PFUser object in swift. 
I also want to declare my own variables. The Parse documentation on subclassing do not cover PFUser at this point.

Parse documentation on subclassing PFObject:

```
class Armor : PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    class func load() {
       self.registerSubclass()
    }
    class func parseClassName() -> String! {
       return "Armor"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**BridgingHeader.h:**

```
#import <Parse/Parse.h>
#import <Parse/PFObject+Subclass.h>
```

**User.swift:**

```
import Foundation

class User : PFUser, PFSubclassing {

override class func load() {
    self.registerSubclass()
}

//My variables
dynamic var firstname: String
dynamic var lastname: String

}
```

**DONT´T include this snippet when subclassing PFUser:**

```
class func parseClassName() -> String! {
    return "User"
}
```

Comment: @NSManaged is specifically for Core Data. Can't you just use `dynamic` now that we have it in swift?

Comment: Nick, no but they´re working on it:
https://www.parse.com/questions/pfsubclassing-in-swift

Comment: That's pretty old (i.e. before the `dynamic` keyword was added to Swift)

Comment: I case someone don´t get the dynamic keyword to work, use @NSManaged instead.

Comment: Do I need to use optional mark? Otherwise xcode complaints about my subclass not having any initializers

Comment: chrs. Yes, or use ! if you´re certain that your variable will have a value. When using ! you also don´t need to unwrap before using the variable.

Comment: With 8.1SDK this worked for me even without the `dynamic` keyword.

Comment: Also if you are calling `self.registerSubclass()` in `load()` there is no need to call `User.registerSubclass()` in the AppDelegate.

Answer (score 8):

In Swift 2.0 You not need to implement **PFSubclassing** Protocol for Subclassing PFUser.

Just create normal subclass like this;

```
class ParseUser: PFUser {

    @NSManaged var name: String?
    @NSManaged var surname: String?
    @NSManaged var phoneNumber: String?

    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }
```

Comment: Given the new best practice for the singleton pattern, can't we replace the `Static` struct with `static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0` alone?

Comment: What is @NSManaged? I dont want to use core data or a local store or something like that.