# Subclassing PFUser in Swift has no member 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock'

Tags: ios, parse-platform, swift2, xcode7, subclassing

I'm subclassing `PFUser` like this:

```
// User.swift
import UIKit
import Parse

class User: PFObject, PFSubclassing {
    override class func initialize() {
        struct Static {
            static var onceToken : dispatch_once_t = 0;
        }
        dispatch_once(&Static.onceToken) {
            self.registerSubclass()
        }
    }

    static func parseClassName() -> String {
        return "_User"
    }
}
```

Then I have a sign up view controller with some text fields and a button action which will sign up the user asynchronously to my Parse app:

```
    // MARK: - Actions
    @IBAction func signUpAction(sender: UIButton) {
        var email = self.emailTextField.text
        var username = self.usernameTextField.text
        var password = self.passwordTextField.text

        // Run a spinner to show a task in progress
        var spinner: UIActivityIndicatorView = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 150, 150)) as UIActivityIndicatorView
        spinner.startAnimating()

        var newUser = User()

        // Sign up the user asynchronously
        newUser.signUpInBackgroundWithBlock({
            (succeed, error) -> Void in

            // Stop the spinner
            spinner.stopAnimating()
            if ((error) != nil) {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Error", message: "\(error)", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()

            } else {
                var alert = UIAlertView(title: "Success", message: "Signed Up", delegate: self, cancelButtonTitle: "OK")
                alert.show()
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in
                    let viewController:UIViewController = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil).instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier("Home") as! UIViewController
                    self.presentViewController(viewController, animated: true, completion: nil)
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

But then I get three compile errors that I don't know how to solve. I've just started using Swift with Parse so I'm a bit confused if I'm doing something wrong when I'm subclassing `PFUser` or if it's something that have to do with the `Parse SDK`

Here are the errors I'm getting:

```
'SignUpViewController.User' does not conform to protocol 'PFSubclassing'

Value of type 'SignUpViewController.User' has no member 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock'

Value of type 'User' has no member 'signUpInBackgroundWithBlock'
```

I've followed the [Parse documentation guide on subclassing](https://parse.com/docs/ios/guide#objects-subclasses) so I would appreciate any help here by you fellow developers!

Comment: This might help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28465023/subclassing-parses-pfuser-in-swift

Comment: Hm no it didn't help @robdashnash