# var newUser = PFUser() it's action does not seem to work?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, parse-platform, swift2

I have a hard time implementing `newUser` with parse. I'm following a tutorial about this sign-up Parse version.

Why is only `password` working and not the other codes?

```
self.actInd.startAnimating()

var newUser = PFUser()
newUser.name = name
newUser.surname = surname
newUser.birth = birth
newuser.email = email
newUser.password = password  <- // why only password works?
newUser.confirmpassword = confirmpassword
```

[image: Why only password works and not the others?]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two things should work: `email` and `password`.

Reason for that is that the [`PFUser`](https://parse.com/docs/osx/api/Classes/PFUser.html) has a couple of properties:

- username
- password
- email

You `email`-line does however not work because you misspelled `newUser` - you wrote `newuser` (lower case `U`)

The "regular" PFUser just does not have the property `confirmPassword` for example - did you somewhere tell the compiler that it should have that property? Same goes for the other properties.

## Solution

Your probably have to create a subclass of `PFUser` and register that subclass - for example like in this question/answer: [Subclass PFUser in swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25388865/subclass-pfuser-in-swift)

Comment: So Parse only has 3 selected properties that work, if I need more I'll have to create them?

**Did you somewhere tell the compiler that it should have that property?:**

`var confirmpassword = self.confirmPasswordField.text`

Do you mean like this?

Comment: Exactly, Parse by default has only those 3 properties for you. But of course you can tell Parse that your user has more than that. An example for how to do that is present in the linked question - i just changed the link destination, you might want tot check the link again ;)

Comment: How do I hug you over the internet? <3 :D Thanks!

Comment: The code line you mention only show you trying to assign something, but you never told Parse that the user actually *has* that property.

Comment: Yeah, I'm getting the hang of it slowly. :D By the way may I add you to facebook or anything else to keep to in touch? =)

Comment: No thanks - but happy to have helped - only thing you can do when you get enough reputation is leave an upvote ;)

Comment: I understand haha xD Just to be precise, when creating the subclass, should I do it in the "sign-up" class or in the Signup button action?

Comment: Or just create another swift file and be done with it. :PP